# How to view installed wine apps to launch them?

Tags: windows, wine, appmenu

I am unable to locate my wine applications in ubuntu, while in lubuntu I have seen a menu option of wine where it shows all the applications installed in wine, is there any way I can view list of installed wine applications.

I have installed sqlyog community and cannot find in start menu :(

Comment: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1328

Comment: Seems to run ok,just search the Dash for the application and it will appear.

Comment: you mean sqlyog, I did but its showing me the exe file which I downloaded to install sqlyog (it is not the sqlyog launcher)